# How to fix javascript code to recognize all photos clicked

Tags: javascript

i'm using this slideshow created by Traversy Media, but trying to alter it so that thumbnails are on top and bottom of the main picture.  The thumbnails on the top work fine, but it isn't recognizing the bottom row of thumbnails when clicked.  Is it possible to split these thumbnails up or do they all have to be within the same div?

This is only recognizing the first 4 images and not the last 4.

here is a fiddle

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0y9nptor/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>thumbgallery</title>

<style type=text/css>
.container {
  max-width: 760px;
  margin: auto;
  border: #fff solid 3px;
  background: #fff;
}

.main-img img,
.imgs img{
  width: 100%;
}

.imgs{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 5px;
}

.imgs img {
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Fade in animation */
@keyframes fadeIn {
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.fade-in {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fadeIn var(--fade-time) ease-in 1 forwards;
}

/* Media Queries */
@media(max-width: 600px) {
  .imgs {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  }
}
<style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

    <div class="imgs">
        <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/gxVppG/img1.jpg">
    <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/iZ3Lww/img2.jpg">
    <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/iQsPOb/img3.jpg">  
    <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/gFFdib/img4.jpg">  
    </div>

    <div class="main-img">
    <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/gxVppG/img1.jpg" id="current">
  </div>

  <div class="imgs">
    <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/hS5ppG/img5.jpg">
    <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/goKtGw/img6.jpg">
    <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/bSWjOb/img7.jpg">
    <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/i2o9pG/img8.jpg">
  </div>


</div>

    <script>
const current = document.querySelector('#current');
const imgs = document.querySelector('.imgs');
const img = document.querySelectorAll('.imgs img');
const opacity = 0.6;

// Set first img opacity
img[0].style.opacity = opacity;

imgs.addEventListener('click', imgClick);

function imgClick(e) {
  // Reset the opacity
  img.forEach(img => (img.style.opacity = 1));

  // Change current image to src of clicked image
  current.src = e.target.src;

  // Add fade in class
  current.classList.add('fade-in');

  // Remove fade-in class after .5 seconds
  setTimeout(() => current.classList.remove('fade-in'), 500);

  // Change the opacity to opacity var
  e.target.style.opacity = opacity;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `document.querySelector('.imgs');` only returns the first match of that class, to fix that `.querySelectorAll()` could be used, but the return will be an NodeList that should be iterated to add the event to all elements.

But that would leave an undesirable behavior that i saw, when clicking between the images will trigger the event and "break" the gallery.

So to avoid that, i added the eventListener only to the `<img>`s.

Snnipet with solution below.

```js
const current = document.querySelector('#current');
const img = document.querySelectorAll('.imgs img');
const opacity = 0.6;

// Set first img opacity
img[0].style.opacity = opacity;

// Iterating over result to add the eventListeners
img.forEach(i => i.addEventListener('click', imgClick));

function imgClick(e) {
  // Reset the opacity
  img.forEach(img => (img.style.opacity = 1));

  // Change current image to src of clicked image
  current.src = e.target.src;

  // Add fade in class
  current.classList.add('fade-in');

  // Remove fade-in class after .5 seconds
  setTimeout(() => current.classList.remove('fade-in'), 500);

  // Change the opacity to opacity var
  e.target.style.opacity = opacity;
}
```

```css
.container {
  max-width: 760px;
  margin: auto;
  border: #fff solid 3px;
  background: #fff;
}

.main-img img,
.imgs img{
  width: 100%;
}

.imgs{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 5px;
}

.imgs img {
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Fade in animation */
@keyframes fadeIn {
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.fade-in {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fadeIn var(--fade-time) ease-in 1 forwards;
}

/* Media Queries */
@media(max-width: 600px) {
  .imgs {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

    <div class="imgs">
        <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/gxVppG/img1.jpg">
    <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/iZ3Lww/img2.jpg">
    <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/iQsPOb/img3.jpg">  
    <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/gFFdib/img4.jpg">  
    </div>

    <div class="main-img">
    <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/gxVppG/img1.jpg" id="current">
  </div>

  <div class="imgs">
    <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/hS5ppG/img5.jpg">
    <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/goKtGw/img6.jpg">
    <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/bSWjOb/img7.jpg">
    <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/i2o9pG/img8.jpg">
  </div>


</div>
```